# ngx-markdown-editor Metadata Version Mismatch Error

Tags: angular

I have an Angular project where I'm using the [`ngx-markdown-editor`](https://npmjs.org/ngx-markdown-editor) package. It works well provided I add the `LMarkdownModule` *after* I've already started the development server. If I already have the modules imported, then I get the following error:

[image]

```
ERROR in Error: Metadata version mismatch for module /path/to/the/project/my-angular-app/node_modules/ngx-markdown-editor/ngx-markdown-editor.d.ts, found version 4, expected 3, resolving symbol SharedModule in /path/to/the/project/my-angular-app/src/app/shared/shared.module.ts, resolving symbol SharedModule in /path/to/the/project/my-angular-app/src/app/shared/shared.module.ts
    at syntaxError (/path/to/the/project/my-angular-app/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:1729:34)
    at simplifyInContext (/path/to/the/project/my-angular-app/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:24979:23)
    at StaticReflector.simplify (/path/to/the/project/my-angular-app/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:24991:13)
    at StaticReflector.annotations (/path/to/the/project/my-angular-app/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:24418:41)
    at _getNgModuleMetadata (/path/to/the/project/my-angular-app/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtools_impl.js:138:31)
    at _extractLazyRoutesFromStaticModule (/path/to/the/project/my-angular-app/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtools_impl.js:109:26)
    at /path/to/the/project/my-angular-app/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtools_impl.js:129:27
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at _extractLazyRoutesFromStaticModule (/path/to/the/project/my-angular-app/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtools_impl.js:128:10)
    at /path/to/the/project/my-angular-app/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtools_impl.js:129:27
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at _extractLazyRoutesFromStaticModule (/path/to/the/project/my-angular-app/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtools_impl.js:128:10)
    at Object.listLazyRoutesOfModule (/path/to/the/project/my-angular-app/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtools_impl.js:53:22)
    at Function.NgTools_InternalApi_NG_2.listLazyRoutes (/path/to/the/project/my-angular-app/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtools_api.js:91:39)
    at AotPlugin._getLazyRoutesFromNgtools (/path/to/the/project/my-angular-app/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/plugin.js:241:66)
    at _donePromise.Promise.resolve.then.then.then.then.then (/path/to/the/project/my-angular-app/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/plugin.js:495:24)
```

Like I said, the weird part is that the app recompiles and the markdown editor appears and works as expected if I add the import of the `LMarkdownModule` after I've already started the dev server. I've tried clearing the package-lock.json file and doing a fresh install of the `node_modules`, but neither of those things made a difference.

Many other similar issues say that there are issues/errors in a specific version of the offending package, but this doesn't seem to be the issue here.

I'm using Angular version 4 on this project, and when I tested the package with Angular 6 I didn't get the same issue, so that could be the problem. But why does it work after I've got the local server running? If there's something I'm missing, I'd be really grateful.